# How to replace as substring of a word using javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, substring

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a regexp pattern with a new word. Currently I can only replace the coinsurance if it is an individual word that separated by space " ", but I would like to replace all of them even if they are in the middle of a word. Here is an example:

for string:
abc:target12 target12 cdtarget23 target

I would like to replace all the occurrences of target[0-9]{2} with "ok", so after the replacement, the new string would be like:
abc:ok ok cdok target

Thanks！

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `g` ([Global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)) at the end of your regex ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4G3m8/)):

```
alert("abc:target12 target12 cdtarget23 target".replace(/target[0-9]{2}/g, 'ok'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use replace like this:

```
var repl = str.replace(/target\d{2}/g, 'ok');
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/hew6oa